# RecyclerView list weirdly displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to display a list of files and folders using a RecyclerView.

Here is the Adapter and the ViewHolder :

```
class FilesRecyclerViewAdapter(private val files: Array<File>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FilesRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_file_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = files[position]
        holder.icon.setImageResource(if (item.isDirectory) R.drawable.folder else R.drawable.file)
        holder.fileName.text = item.name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = files.size

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val icon: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.icon)
        val fileName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fileName)
    }

}
```

The layout for a single item in the list (R.layout.fragment_file_item) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fileItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/file_item_height">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fileName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:text="Element"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how it's included into the main activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fileSystem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally the code in the `onCreate` function of the main activity :

```
private lateinit var fileSystem: RecyclerView
// Later in the code
fileSystem = findViewById(R.id.fileSystem)
fileSystem.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
fileSystem.adapter = FilesRecyclerViewAdapter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles())
```

I expected to have a list of items with the icon on the left and the name of the folder slighly to the right like on the item layout preview :

[image]

Instead, I have this mess :

[image]

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` makes your `RecyclerView` start on 50% of view.

Remove it, if you dont need them

Comment: I removed the horizontal bias but the result is the same, I've checked there was no "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" left in the code, je folder icons are still in the middle of the screen